How to control the name of a reusable workflow?
I am trying to call a reusable workflow but the name of the workflow in GitHub Actions tab is always {caller_job}/{reusable_job}:

I want to override this name completely.
I have tried naming the caller job and the workflow but nothing worked.
Even if the name of the calling job is empty it still shows a / in the name.
invoke_release_workflow:
  name: ' '
  ...

Is this even possible?
thanks.
